# SendTransactionAsync vs CallAsync

Tags: transactions

Can some one kind enough to tell me what are the differences between the 2?

I found that SendTransactionAsync works most of the time, but I can't get the returns value from a contract function. :(

Sorry if you think that this is a very simple question, I did search in google, but can't find definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are sent to the network, have no accessible return value, have transaction fees, and can result in state changes.

Calls are processed locally on a single node, have a return value, have no transaction fees, and cannot change any state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it means that all functions require state changes shouldn't have a return value at all? Since we can never get the return value?

Comment: You can still see the return value if you call the function from another function (in the same contract or another contract).